# How to set control.focus in a user control with net maui

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm working with Net Maui and I have a problem setting focus in a control.
I created a ContentView with 1 label and 3 entries mi code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NautorStar.MisControles.HoraControl">
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>

    <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label x:Name="lblHora"
               Text="Hora Reloj Bitacora "
               FontSize="16"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Entry x:Name="enHoras"
               Text = "{TemplateBinding HoraIntroducida}"
               Completed="Horas_Completed"
               HeightRequest="40"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"                  
               Keyboard="Numeric"
               Margin="5,0,5,0"
               MaxLength="2"

                WidthRequest="40"/>
        <Entry x:Name="enMinutos"
               Text = "{TemplateBinding MinutosIntroducidos}"    
               Completed="Minutos_Completed"
               HeightRequest="40"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
               Keyboard="Numeric"
               Margin="0,0,5,0"
               MaxLength="2"
               Placeholder="Minutos"                 

                WidthRequest="40"/>
        <Entry x:Name="enSegundos"
               Text = "{TemplateBinding SegundosIntroducidos}"     
               Completed="Segundos_Completed"
               HeightRequest="40"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
               Keyboard="Numeric"
               Margin="0,0,5,0"
               MaxLength="2"
               Placeholder="Segundos"
               WidthRequest="40"/>
        
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>
```

The c# code is

```
public partial class HoraControl : ContentView
{
    // Definimos las propiedades del control
    public string Titulo
    {
        get => GetValue(TituloPrperty) as string;
        set => SetValue(TituloPrperty, value);
    }
    public string HoraIntroducida
    {
        get => GetValue(HoraIntroducidaProperty) as string;
        set => SetValue(HoraIntroducidaProperty, value);
    }
    public string MinutosIntroducidos
    {
        get => GetValue(MinutosIntroducidosProperty) as string;
        set => SetValue(MinutosIntroducidosProperty, value);
    }
    public string SegundosIntroducidos
    {
        get => GetValue(SegundosIntroducidosProperty) as string;
        set => SetValue(SegundosIntroducidosProperty, value);
    }
    // Aceptar los nuevos valores
    public static BindableProperty TituloPrperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Titulo), typeof(string), typeof(HoraControl));
    // Aceptar los nuevos valores de Hora
    public static BindableProperty HoraIntroducidaProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HoraIntroducida), typeof(string), typeof(HoraControl));
    // Aceptar los nuevos valores de Minutos
    public static BindableProperty MinutosIntroducidosProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MinutosIntroducidos), typeof(string), typeof(HoraControl));

    // Aceptar los nuevos valores de Minutos
    public static BindableProperty SegundosIntroducidosProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SegundosIntroducidos), typeof(string), typeof(HoraControl));

    public HoraControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HoraIntroducida = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
        MinutosIntroducidos = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
        SegundosIntroducidos = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
    }
    void Horas_Completed(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HoraIntroducida = ValidacionDatos.ValidarHora(HoraIntroducida);
        FindNextEntry();
        //enMinutos?.Focus();

    }
    void Minutos_Completed(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MinutosIntroducidos = ValidacionDatos.ValidarMinutos(MinutosIntroducidos);
        FindNextEntry();
        //enSegundos?.Focus();
    }
    void Segundos_Completed(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SegundosIntroducidos = ValidacionDatos.ValidarSegundos(SegundosIntroducidos);
    }
    // Buscar el siguiente Entry
    private Entry FindNextEntry()
    {
        var currentParent = this.Parent;
        if (currentParent is Layout layout)
        {
            int index = layout.Children.IndexOf(this);
            if (index >= 0 && index < layout.Children.Count - 1)
            {
                // Encontrar el siguiente Entry dentro del mismo Layout.
                for (int i = index + 1; i < layout.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (layout.Children[i] is Entry nextEntry)
                    {
                        //return nextEntry;
                        nextEntry.Focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null; // No se encontró ningún Entry siguiente válido.
    }
}
```

The problem I have is I can´t use enMinutos?.Focus(); because I have the error telling that the enMinutos does not exist in the current context.
I try to use the FindNextEntry, but always return null, because did  not find an Entry.
Any ideas to be able to set focus to the next Entry??
Thanks

Comment: Unless you know you need it, take out all xaml lines that refer to `ControlTemplate`. Having a Template can be convenient for some purposes, but makes it harder to refer to the parts of the Template.

Comment: I need the ControlTemplate, because I have to reference it in another page

Comment: There might be a different way to reach your goal. Please add to question the xaml/code that references the template. (It is not possible to reference parts of a control template, from the contentview’s code behind, because the only situation in which a template is needed, is whenit might be replaced by a different template. This of course would crash any code that tried to access part of the original template.)

Comment: Can you give link to doc or example you based your code on? I suspect it was solving a slightly different situation (that did require a Template).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reference parts of a control template, from the contentview’s code behind, because the only situation in which a template is needed, is when it might be replaced by a different template.
Replacing the template from code elsewhere would **crash any code** that tried to access part of the original template.

If you need to replace the template, add to question all uses of this ContentView. There must be a different way to reach your goal.

———————————————

If you don’t need to replace the template, then the fix is to not define those elements inside a Template.

A ContentView can have any contents; the elements you show can be added directly to the ContentView, without wrapping in `ControlTemplate`:

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NautorStar.MisControles.HoraControl">
    <HorizontalStackLayout ..
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will remove the ControlTemplate and I will try something different.